# Can I pass an array of object to filterBy?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My ember version is `1.13` and I would like to ask if the line of code below is applicable to the version of my ember app above?

`console.log(this.get('arrayOfObjects').filterBy('zoneName', ['zoneNameOne', 'zoneNameTwo']));` ?

Sample data of `selectedZoneOrCityName` is

`selectedZoneOrCityName = ['zoneNameOne', 'zoneNameTwo'],`

I want to use it something like these

```
if (selectedZoneOrCityName) {
  return this.get('arrayOfObjects').filterBy('zoneName', selectedZoneOrCityName).mapBy('cityName');
} else {
  console.log('reads nothing');
  return [];
}
```

Comment: can you post `selectedZoneOrCityName` & `arrayOfObjects` sample data also.

Comment: hi @ShivKumarBaghel edit is made, please take a look at the updated question. Thank you!

Comment: hi @ShivKumarBaghel I don't think version `1.13` does support that kind of `filterBy`

Comment: please post `arrayOfObjects` sample data also for better assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simple `filter` like below code snippet.

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'one',
    zoneName: 'zoneNameOne'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'two',
    zoneName: 'one zoneName'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'three',
    zoneName: 'zoneNameOne'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'four',
    zoneName: 'zoneNameTwo'
  }
];

var selectedZoneOrCityName = ['zoneNameOne', 'zoneNameTwo'];
 arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.filter((item) => {
   return selectedZoneOrCityName.includes(item.zoneName);
 });
 
 console.log('final filtered array : ', arrayOfObjects);
```

if you are usign `filterBy` then you have to `chain` filterBy for each array value.

Comment: Hi, but then how would you achieve the `mapBy` function there? Also, i think it should be `.includes(item.get('zoneName'));`

Comment: you can use the above solution in your way. i assume `arrayOfObjects` only.